# responseXML displaying as null even though xhr object shows it as set

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code which eventually populates a table. At this point I create an XHR, where on load it will call my employee collections process XML function

```
EmployeeCollection.prototype.fetchXML = function(path, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onload = this.processXML(xhr, callback);
};

EmployeeCollection.prototype.processXML = function(xhr, callback) {
     console.log(xhr); // this shows an XHR object with 
                       // readyState: 4 and responseXML: document

     console.log(xhr.responseXML); // null
}
```

My question is; how come I can see the responseXML as a document if I access the xhr object and expand the node in the console, yet when I try to directly access this property of the xhr object - I can't?

Comment: You are calling the function, not assigning it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is you are calling the method and assigning what it returns to the onload. So when you are "assiging" it is calling the method before the Ajax call has actually loaded.

```
xhr.onload = this.processXML(xhr, callback);
```

It should be

```
xhr.onload = this.processXML.bind(this, xhr, callback);
```

or

```
var that = this;
xhr.onload = function () { that.processXML(xhr, callback); };
```

Comment: bind() worked fine for me, time to read up on what that does then! Thanks alot man.

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be evaluation of object values at the time you expand it in your browser developer tools. For example, at the moment you have `null` in your `console.log` - it has been logged at the time of execution.

But second `console.log` which gives you `document` value is evaluated at the time you expand it in your console window (later).

Comment: I'm logging both values at exactly the same time, though.

Comment: Yeah, but imagine `xhr.responseXML` isn't set at that time, BUT `xhr` object is set (it doesn't log null) - that's why you can browse through it in your window and see its properties. Then it's property - `responseXML` is set later AND evaluated later by you when you click expand in your console.

Comment: So the values being set are the values at the time of assigning this function to `onload`, however when I attempt to log the xhr object, it is showing me the xhr object at the time of logging? that makes sense.

Comment: All I'm saying is when you browse through `xhr` object in your console developer tools you do like lots of smaller `console.log(xhr.propertyA)` logs AT LATER TIME compared to directly programatically accessing `console.log(xhr.responseXML)`. It's null at given time and it's evaluated immediately compared to digging into not-null `xhr` object later in your console and inspecting it's properties which can be set.

Comment: If when I logged my object properties they were logged at a later time, then they wouldn't be null. When I log the object itself it indicates that they are not null at the time of logging. This is presumably because it is logging the object at the time that log occurs; however when I attempt to log the properties; presumably it's logging them at the point of setting this function to xhr.onload

Comment: Yes. Exactly: "logging the object at the time that log occurs".

Comment: Right. I replied to your comment before you made your edit by the way; it makes sense now.